# Prove or disprove: If $(X,<)$ is well-ordered then $Y'=\{x\in X : f(x)< x\}=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**My claim.** Let $(X,<)$ be a well-ordered set, $Y$ and $<$-section and $f:X\rightarrow X$ an order-preserving function. Then

$$
Y'=\{x\in X : f(x)< x \} = \emptyset .
$$

*My proof.*

1.- If $f=\mbox{id}_X$ then $Y'$ is celarly empty, since well-orders are asymmetric binary relations.

2.- If $f\not=\mbox{id}_X$ $Y'$ may be different from $\emptyset$. So suppose $Y'\neq \emptyset$. Then there exists a least element $y_0\in Y'$. However since it belongs to $Y'$, $f(y_0)<y_0$ (Does it shows $Y'$ is not a $<$-section?).

Moreover, since $f(y_0)\notin Y'$, then $f(y_0)<f(f(y_0))$. On the other hand, since $f$ is order-preserving, $f(f(y_0))<f(y_0)$.

*Remark.* The above statement is written in my book but it considers order-preserving mapps and it is used to show that if $Y$ is an $<$-section, then

$$\not\exists y\in Y:f(y)<y$$,

but I think this is a corollary. The theorem statement is much more strong, no?

Comment: $\{1,2\}$ is well-ordered with its usual order. Take $f(2)=1$ and $f(1)=2$. Then $W=\{2\}.$

Comment: You don't have any restrictions on the function that is related to the ordering. If a set $X$ is well-ordered, then it can be well-ordered in a _lot_ of different ways. Claiming that this holds simultaneously for the same $f$ but a lot of different $<$ seems unreasonable.

Comment: @treeleaf: So your comment proves $f$ must be order-preserving. And then the proof is not so easy as I have written.

Comment: My fault is that $f(w_0)<w_0$ not proves $W$ hasn't got least element, but $f(w_0)$ is not in $W$. However, if $W$ would be a $<$-section, then $f(w_0)$ must be in $W$.

Comment: Please see my edits.